# Spring java config extending an abstract configuration

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

in our software we are using spring java config. We have a setup, where one configuration extends an abstract configuration. Please have a look at this testcase:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

public class SpringConfigTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
        ctx.getBeansOfType(AtomicInteger.class).entrySet().stream().forEach(b -> System.out.println(b.getKey() + " : " + b.getValue() + " (" + b.getValue().hashCode() + ")"));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class MyConfig extends AbstractConfig {

        @Bean(name = "anotherName")
        public AtomicInteger myBean() {
            return new AtomicInteger(5);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractConfig {

        @Bean
        public AtomicInteger myBean() {
            return new AtomicInteger(10);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, that `MyConfig` overwrites `AbstractConfig` and in the created ApplicationContext there is only one bean of type `AtomicInteger` under the name `anotherName`.

The results was:

```
anotherName : 5 (2109798150)
myBean : 5 (1074389766)
```

So it says, there are two beans (two instances - one for each name) - and even more surpring: the same method (`MyConfig#myBean()`) was used to create both of them.

This behaviour looks odd to us: We expected that spring would either respect the usual java way of inheritance and create only the bean from `MyConfig`... or at least would create two independent beans ("10" and "5") in case it sees `AbstractConfig` as an independant config.

While investigating this we also tried to register the method name on the `MyConfig` class:

```java
public static class MyConfig extends AbstractConfig {

    @Bean(name = ["anotherName", "myBean"])
    public AtomicInteger myBean() {
    ...
```

and this time we got only one bean:
`anotherName : 5 (2109798150)`

.. what was even more surprising for us.

Does anybody know if this is really the correct behaviour or are we only using it wrong? Should we raise a ticket in spring's jira?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your use case to make a spring java configuration abstract?

Comment: We're using spring-data-mongodb and we're connecting to two different databases in our application. So we're overriding [AbstractMongoConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoConfiguration.html) twice but have to rename some of the beans so we can find them in other places. But now we've seen that they're three times in our appCtx...

Comment: Is this perhaps related to component scan path issues? Maybe you can avoid scanning the mongodb packages? Or is that required for spring data to work with mongodb?

Comment: No it's not part of our classpath scanning. Only the two deriving classes are scanned automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Spring pro, but I'd say that behaviour is by design. To achieve what you want (I hope I guessed right) "inject this bean instead of the other" you would use [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) on a bean, to selectively enable a configuration depending on circumstances you would use a [@Conditional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) i.e. [@Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response!
<code>@Primary</code> would only solve the problem problem of injection. But still two beans are created (with all their lifecycle - that's what my question is about). We're not sure if this is wrong.
<code>@Conditional</code> is not an option for us. The

Comment: So IIUC your question is if there can exist more than one bean sharing the same name?

Comment: No, the name is different. The question is: I extend from an abstract configuration (which is not annotated with `@Configuration`), overwite the `@Bean`-method and change only the name attribute: Is it correct, that spring creates - only in this special case - two beans? (If I spare out the name attribute; only one bean is created). This seems odd to us.

Comment: I'd say that is correct because bean creation is done by reflection/proxying for every distinct bean id/name that is found during component scanning. I think that the original configuration is abstract doesn't matter to that process. At least the documentation doesn't say anything else: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, beans can be wired by type first, but then by name.
Hence @Qualifier("myBeanName") can disambiguate autowiring multiple beans with the same type, e.g.

So:
the very fact that the non-abstract bean has been given another name, causes it to be considered a different bean in the application context.

You can declare beans in a non-configuration class.  That is called "lite" mode, but it is still a bean in the application context.
See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256702/spring-bean-can-still-work-without-configuration) answer on lite mode.

I didn't know one could give a bean more than one name, but since Spring beans are singletons by default, it stands to reason only one bean would be created in the second case, as "myBean" already exists and only one bean with that name can be in the application context.