# Spring: @Bean can still work without @Configuration

Tags: spring

From https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ I have a spring framework hellpworld program. I delete the annotation `@Configuration`. However the program could still run as before. Why? What is `@Configuration` role here?

Answer (score 27):

You can still mark the class with @Component for @Bean instances to be available to program. when you do that it is called lite mode. In this mode you can not use 'inter-bean references' , means referring other instance via methods.

On the the other hand @Bean with class @Configuration is wrapped in side cglib wrapper where any calls to this bean methods can be intercepted and bean instances can be return from context. Means you can use 'inter-bean references'.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

1. @Bean Methods in @Configuration Classes

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes.
>   In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the
>   same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references
>   between beans are strongly typed and navigable. Such so-called
>   'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP
>   semantics, just like getBean() lookups would. These are the semantics
>   known from the original 'Spring JavaConfig' project which require
>   CGLIB subclassing of each such configuration class at runtime. As a
>   consequence, @Configuration classes and their factory methods must not
>   be marked as final or private in this mode.

- @Bean Lite Mode

> @Bean methods may also be declared within classes that are not
>   annotated with @Configuration. For example, bean methods may be
>   declared in a @Component class or even in a plain old class. In such
>   cases, a @Bean method will get processed in a so-called 'lite' mode.
>
> Bean methods in lite mode will be treated as plain factory methods by
>   the container (similar to factory-method declarations in XML), with
>   scoping and lifecycle callbacks properly applied. The containing class
>   remains unmodified in this case, and there are no unusual constraints
>   for the containing class or the factory methods.
>
> In contrast to the semantics for bean methods in @Configuration
>   classes, 'inter-bean references' are not supported in lite mode.
>   Instead, when one @Bean-method invokes another @Bean-method in lite
>   mode, the invocation is a standard Java method invocation; Spring does
>   not intercept the invocation via a CGLIB proxy.

And,
@Configuration gives you the ability use many other features with conjunction of other annotations

Importing other config
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)

resource import @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")

enable component scan @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sample.*" })

marking profile  @Profile("production")

To enable features @Enablexxxx

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html